# is it possible to call API through Glance apple watch using NSUserActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, openstack-glance

as apple suggested use [Handoff](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/) in Glance . 
I wants to call web API in Glance Interface , for this I did following things

```
    - (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
    {
        [super awakeWithContext:context];   
        [self CreateUaerActivity];   
    }
    -(void)CreateUaerActivity
    {
        NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"com.xxx.xxx.glance"];    
        activity.title = @"Glance";
        activity.delegate=self;
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kUserLoginWatchKit,kRequestTypeWatchKit, nil];
        activity.userInfo = dict;
        self.userActivity = activity;
        [self.userActivity becomeCurrent];
    }

- (void)willActivate
{

    [super willActivate];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }
-(void)doSomething
{

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kUserLoginWatchKit,kRequestTypeWatchKit, nil];
    [super updateUserActivity:@"com.xxx.xxx.glance" userInfo:dict webpageURL:nil];
 }
-(void)handleUserActivity:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
//displaying data    
}
```

and in **AppDelegate.m** file  -

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
    {
        NSLog(@"Handoff dictionary: %@", userActivity.userInfo);
         NSString *requestType = userActivity.userInfo[kRequestTypeWatchKit];
    if ([requestType  isEqual: kGlanceDataWatchKit])
    {
//calling web API to get Data
}
  return YES;
  }
```

I found AppDelegate never called **continueUserActivity** method to return something to Glance interface.
please guide me how to call API through Glance Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to call an web Api i suggest yout to do it like this :

in the GlanceInterfaceController :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dictionary setObject:@"getSomething" forKey:@"action"];        
    [MainInterfaceController openParentApplication:dictionary reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Reply received by Watch app: %@", replyInfo); // the reply from the appDelegate... 
         }
```

in your parent's app Delegate :

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
       NSLog(@"Request received by iOS app");
if( [userInfo objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"getSomething"] ){
//call you're Web API
//send the reponse to you're glance :              

reply(DictResponse);// some Dictionary from your web API... 

}
```

*****EDIT*****

i've been issued the same issue, one easy fix is to begin an background task, from  : 
[fiveminutewatchkit](http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/11/one-weird-trick-to-fix-openparentapplicationreply)

Here's the way :

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    // Temporary fix, I hope.
    // --------------------
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bogusWorkaroundTask;
    bogusWorkaroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bogusWorkaroundTask];
    }];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bogusWorkaroundTask];
    });
    // --------------------

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier realBackgroundTask;
    realBackgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            reply(nil);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];
        }];

        // Kick off a network request, heavy processing work, etc.

        // Return any data you need to, obviously.
        reply(nil);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:realBackgroundTask];
}
```

in fact iOS kill your parent's app before you can retrieve data... this (not very clean solution) prevent you're app to be killed... and let you the time to retrieve infos...

******END EDIT******

Comment: Hi Jeremy , I already implemented it & Apple Happily approved my application , but when I tested my application on actually Apple Watch Device , I always needs to launch my application on iPhone device to get the updates in Glance . I needs to make separate API call which will not look the parent application.

Comment: see edited awnser, hope that will help you, i have two apps approved on the store with this.